# How to access individual variable inside of a 2d array Actionscript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

Im trying to access an individual tile inside of my 2d array of tiles
Ive created my array like so:

```
private var map:Array = [[25,25]];
```

ive tried several ways including:

```
map[1][1] = 1;
```

all that does is give me this:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property 1 on Number.
```

ive also tried:

```
map[[1,1]] = 1;
```

nothing happends that I can tell

The only way that ive tried so far that gets me a result thats not an error is:

```
map[1,1] = 1;
```

The issue here is this selects the whole row.
Any help would be apreciated..thanks!

Comment: Besides the fact that this error can never occour with the code you are showing here... you are aware that array indices are zero based?

Comment: well, I got that error....and im not too certain about your second statement if you mean they start at 0, then im aware... these were just examples of my attempts to get what I want to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct way to create 2D array:

```
private var map:Array = [[25,25]];
```

This array contains one array which contains two elements. You can't address to the second element like this:

```
map[1][1] = 1;
```

because the second element (array) of `map` doesn't exist.

You can create 2D array this way:

```
var map:Array = [];
for (var i:int = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    map[i] = [];// this line adds new row to the 2D array

    // To fill the array by zeros add next loop
    for (var j:int = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        map[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To start, I think that to get the error mentioned in your question, your array should looks like this :

```
var map:Array = [
    [25, 25],     // map[0] = [25, 25] ( array of two elements )
    35            // map[1] = 35 ( just a simple number )
];
```

So, if you write :

```
trace(typeof map[1]);  // gives : number
```

You will get : `number`, and that's why you can not right : `map[1][1] = value;` and it's normal that you got the `#1056` error.

Here, I don't know if you meant assign the value `1` to your 2nd `25` of `map[0]` or you want really add or edit `map[1][1]`, in the 1st case, you can simply write :

```
map[0][1] = 1;    // gives : map[0] = [25, 1]
```

In the 2nd case, you can do :

```
map[1] = [any_other_value, 1];  // gives : map[1] = [any_other_value, 1]
```

Last remark, forget that you got an error and suppose that your `map` array was just:

```
var map:Array = [
    [25, 25]
];
```

Here, you can not also write `map[1][1] = value;`, why ? Let's use the same method :

```
trace(map[1]);   // gives : undefined
```

So sure you can not add a property to an `undefined`, that's why when you write :

```
map[1][1] = value;
```

You will get an `#1010` error : "undefined has no properties. ".

Of course here, we should firstly create `map[1]` :

```
map[1] = [];   // or directly map[1] = [any_other_value, value]
```

And then :

```
map[1][1] = value;
```

Hope that can help.